# PHP regex to convert span element into input

Tags: php, regex

I have a question regarding PHP regexes. 
How can one convert a text/string from the **source format** to a text/string like the **target format**? How can this be accomplished with php regex?

**Source format:**

```
What a <word>sily</word> <word>ting</word> love is!
```

**Target format:**

```
What a <input type="text" class="misspelled-word" value="sily"> <input type="text" class="misspelled-word" value="ting"> love is!
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried already? Please share your code. What are the problems you've encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't even know the basics. Give a read to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get a basic knowledge on how to use regular expressions in PHP.

Anyway, the replacement is really simple:

```
<?php
$string = 'What a <word>sily</word> <word>ting</word> love is!';
$pattern = '/<word>(\w+)<\/word>/';
$replacement = '<input type="text" class="misspelled-word" value="$1">';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

See also a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UNap17/1).

Comment: Thank you wonderful person! You saved my day and I learned something new! Thank you!